# WebDriver in library not found

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a library that I want to put ChromeDriver and IEDriver in so I don't have to reference those executables from each of my different testing frameworks. I have run into an issue, though, where my testing framework is looking for the drivers in the frameworks solution directory, when they exist within the library that I'm referencing. How do I solve this? Am I even going about it the right way?

Comment: Since you are using C#, you can handle this through NuGet package. is that a possiblity?

Comment: I have tried this route. I downloaded the nuget packages for ChromeDriver and IEServer and they did not work.

Comment: See the answer and let me know if that works for you

Comment: Shot... I meant to say Shot.

Comment: I do that all the time. No worries. Dis that work for you though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull down the intended package through NuGet. Then Right click on on the test project>add existing>navigate to the package directory(ie chrome) and add as shown as follows.

**See the [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/9HvygCw6t)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I already tried this yesterday and it didn't fix the issue. I tried it again this morning with the same results. It's weird because you'd  think it would see the drivers in the library.

Comment: It says that the chromedriver.exe cannot be found and it gives a link to go download it.

Comment: Are you adding the existing item from Package through? As shown on image #2?

Comment: I don't know any bog or anything right now. Is it possible for you to make a [screencast](https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) and share of how/which library you are adding? I follow the same mechanism and it works perfectly

Comment: I can't do that due to security reasons. I can try and explain step by step:
I added the nuget packages to my library, which I call DriverFactory. I then follow your instructions above. I build the library and then reference the DriverFactory.dll in my testing framework, which I call TestFramework. I have removed the chromedriver and IEDriver from TestFramework with the intent of using the drivers I have in the DriverFactory.dll.

Comment: @sparkyShorts Added screencast to the answer. Take a look

Comment: I can do that just fine. You may have misunderstood what I'm trying to do: That solution you created in your screencast, i make that a library and reference its .dll in a different solution so I don't have to add webdrivers to every test framework I have.

Comment: What do you mean by different test framework? different projects? And, what is the issue? Sharing the driver executable or instantiating the driver from different cs files?

Comment: See my other question, I think that I phrased it a little better than this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173350/copy-resource-to-bin-from-dll