# Copy resource to bin from dll

Tags: c#

Assume that we have a library Foo. Foo has some resources that are copied to the bin when it is built.

Assume that we have a solution Bar. We reference Foo in Bar, and want the resource files that Foo has in Bar's bin directory. Is this possible? Specifically, can this be done with executables?

Comment: Google "C# Reflection"

Comment: I will go and read up on that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options at least.

One is to make Foo a dependency of Bar. In other words, add the Foo project to Bar's dependencies, then set the reference properties for Foo to "Copy Local: True".

Another way to have a little more control over what happens post-build is to write your own post-build script and have it execute on successful build.

For example, whenever I do a build of project Foo I might want to copy the output to a deployment directory. To do this, I could add the following to the build events (project properties --> Build Events --> Post-build event command line)

```
$(ProjectDir)PostBuild.bat $(ProjectName) $(Platform) $(Configuration)
```

This runs my batch file, PostBuild.bat, and includes some variables that the batch file is expecting. The batch file looks like this:

```
REM A list of all Macros --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

@ECHO off

REM Kill the built app if we forgot to...
TSKILL %1

REM Make the target dir if it doesn't exist
IF NOT EXIST C:\DeploymentDirectory\%1 mkdir C:\DeploymentDirectory\%1

ROBOCOPY E:\repos\MyFooProject\%1\%1\bin\%2\%3\ C:\DeploymentDirectory\%1\ *.dll *.xml *.exe *.pdb *.config /purge

DEL C:\DeploymentDirectory\%1\*.vshost.*

REM Robocopy always exits with a code, which will cause 
REM VS to think something bad happened :-(
REM So the following is to handle that

if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 8 goto failed

rem End of batch file
GOTO success

:failed
rem Do not pause as it will pause msbuild.
exit

:success
exit 0
```

Comment: I added copy local to true, but this did not add the libraries bin to my solution bin. By dependency, do you mean adding the reference to the dll?

Comment: Maybe I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do. You want to have the build output of one project be automatically included in the output of a second project. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. That is what I am going for.

Comment: So, if you add a reference to the DLL or project, then on that reference's properties you choose Copy Local == true, it will copy that reference to the same directory in which your project gets built. Can you try that?

Comment: Affirmative, that's what I have done. I am not having issues getting the .dll in the output directory. I want the output (the bin that contains any exe's) contents from the dll in the project that references the .dll (so I don't have to add the exe's in my solution). Does that make sense? Sorry, this is probably confusing as to what i'm trying to do (it may or may not be possible).

Comment: Let me see if I understand: Project A builds a DLL. You use that DLL as a reference in Project B. When you build Project B, you then want that DLL *and* the exe(s) from Project B to be moved back over to Project A's bin directory? Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, you can adapt the batch file script I wrote in the answer above. Instead of copying the post build files to "C:\DeploymentDirectory" like I had in my example, copy them to your desired directory. Then make sure you add that to the post-build actions like I described. It will then run every time after a successful build of Project B.

Comment: Thanks for being patient! I appreciate the help